# How do calls to the execvp system call work?

Tags: c, exec, system-calls

I was doing a research into the contents of another StackOverflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49929250/printf-terminates-c-program) and I thought it was a good time to brush up my knowledge of unix system calls.

While experimenting with `execvp` (**WITHOUT** fork on purpose) I ran into something that confuses me

I wrote 4 test programs

#### Program 1

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
        //printf("Doge\n");
        execvp("ls");
        printf("Foo\n");
        return 0;
}
```

The program works as expected, the contents of the directory are printed  and the `Foo` print statement is not

#### Program 2

However when I uncomment the first print statement and have the program be this

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
        printf("Doge\n");
        execvp("ls");
        printf("Foo\n");
        return 0;
}
```

`execvp` returns a `-1` and both print statements are issued. why?

#### Program 3

I vaguely remember having to use `unistd.h` when experimenting with unix system calls from college.

So I included it, but not `execvp` has a different signature and it needed some more args than just the name of the program. So I did this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
        printf("Doge\n");
        char *const parmList[] = {"ls", NULL};
        execvp("ls", parmList);
        printf("Foo\n");
        return 0;
}
```

And this works. This has confused me. Why did exec work in the first program? 
I also used [This](http://www.di.uevora.pt/~lmr/syscalls.html)  as a reference to the system calls.

Finally I wrote

#### Program 4

```
#include <stdio.h>
//#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
        printf("Doge\n");
        char *const parmList[] = {"ls", NULL};
        execvp("ls", parmList);
        printf("Foo\n");
        return 0;
}
```

Which also works as expected.

Can someone explain what's going on?

Comment: `execvp("ls");` is undefined behaviour: second parameter is the argument list. You're passing trash.

Comment: but why does it only complain about that in the form of a compiler error when I include `unistd.h`? Also if `execp` is only ever defined with 2 args why does it even let me `execvp("ls")` ?

Comment: without warning options, `execvp` is silently implicitly declared, argument list isn't checked.

Comment: excuse my ignorance but what does *silently implicitly declared, argument list isn't checked* mean? if `execp` is defined in `unistd` how am I even able to run it without including it?

Comment: because compilers are permissive, that's why the maximum level of warnings must be set, always.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With this snippet

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
        execvp("ls");
        printf("Foo\n");
        return 0;
}
```

you're invoking *undefined behaviour*. You're not providing the prototype for `execvp` which requires an argument list (null terminated) as a second parameter.

Using `gcc` without any warning option silently uses `execvp` as implicitly declared, and doesn't check parameters. It just calls the function. The function then looks for a second parameter and encounters... whatever is left of the call stack (or registers, depending on call conventions), that's why a previous `printf` call can change the behaviour.

Using `gcc -Wall` gives the following warning:

```
test.c:5:9: warning: implicit declaration of function 'execvp' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
         execvp("ls");
```

Including the proper include (`#include <unistd.h>`) leads to:

```
test.c:6:9: error: too few arguments to function 'execvp'
         execvp("ls");
         ^~~~~~
```

That's why you've got strange behaviour. Don't look further. Use `execvp` with 2 arguments, period. In your case "Program 3" is the way to go, and always set warning level to the maximum, if possible (`gcc` and `clang`: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Werror`)

Comment: Thanks, this clears it up. I had no idead that gcc could sometimes use implicit declarations of functions likes that. I think `-Wall` is going to be a mainstay for me going forward :)

Comment: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Werror` should be default. But sometimes you're encountering crap code that "cannot be modified"...

Comment: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Werror` sound brilliant. I just tried it out and I really like it. Thanks for this gem :)